# jQuery Select element if has specific content

Tags: jquery

I need to select the list element that has the content "tree", this element can be in any position and the original list has a lot of results.

```
<ul>
   <li>House</li>
   <li>Table</li>
   <li>Tree</li>
   <li>Boat</li>
</ul>
```

How do I check with jquery if the

has the content of "tree"? If it does, I need to add a specific class to it. I know how to add the class, but I don't know how to check for the "content".

Help?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jquery contains selector (http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
 $("ul li:contains('tree')")
```

will get the element with 'tree' as text

Comment: this is correct too :-) and probably a better approach. depends on what jquery is doing behind the scenes

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul li').each( function(){
  var jThis = $(this);
  if(jThis.text() === "Tree"){
    jThis.addClass('myClass');
  }
});
```

Comment: i was almost there ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Whiirrrr, Whiz, Bang, Googling that for you now.

Suggested google query:  "jquery selector content"

First result:  http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

`$(":contains(text)")`

Description: Select all elements that contain the specified text.

text: A string of text to look for. It is case sensitive. 
(It is also quoted)

Their Example:

Finds all divs containing "John" and underlines them.

`$( "div:contains('John')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );`

Your problem:

`$("li:contains('Tree')").addClass("someClass");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "ul li:contains('tree')" );
```

reference [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$function(){
   $("ul li:contains('Tree')").addClass('clsName');
});
```

Read [contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains)